# Irssi in tmux - Messages overwritten

Tags: tmux, irc, irssi

I'm trying to run Irssi in tmux, and I've been coming across something strange. Whenever a new message is received, it overwrites the last message. For example, say the following chat log is in my window:

```
<User Foo> message 1
<User Bar> message 2
<User Baz> message 3
```

If I receive a new message, the expected new layout (how it looks in a terminal not using tmux) would be:

```
<User Foo> message 1
<User Bar> message 2
<User Baz> message 3
<User Grok> new message
```

However, instead it looks like:

```
<User Foo> message 1
<User Bar> message 2
<User Grok> new message
```

Even worse, if several users send messages in quick succession, the messages will all overwrite each other, making the chat nigh unreadable. I can make the complete log appear by switching to another window and switching back, but this is inconvenient and prevents effective communication. I've done some research on the issue with no success. Any ideas about what's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. I had `TERM` set to the wrong value, putting `[ -n "$TMUX" ] && export TERM=screen-256color` in my ~/.bashrc fixed it.